# Use consul key value store instead of chef databags?

Tags: chef-infra, consul

I've tried googling for this but I can't seem to find anything on using consul's kv store instead of chef's databags.  Does anyone have any suggestion on how this can be done?  Is it a bad idea?
I've found 'consul_kv' cookbook but it's for setting and deleting kv pairs in consul from chef.  I'm looking for a way to read kv pairs from consul instead of using chef attributes and databag items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mean you just do it. Use any of the Ruby Consul client libraries that exist (install via either a `gem` line in the `metadata.rb` or a `chef_gem` resource). Because Chef is just plain old Ruby under the hood, you don't need to do anything special. Make sure you are careful about Chef's [two-pass loading model](https://coderanger.net/two-pass/) so you don't try to connect to Consul before it is installed/available, but otherwise just like any other Ruby code.

Comment: Thanks!  I was focusing on a cookbook that will provide the ability.  I found a gem called Diplomat that interacts with consul.  I'll try that out.

Comment: It worked great.  Diplomat makes it really easy and seems to have the most comprehensive support for interactiing with consul's services not just kv.  As to wether or not this is the best way to do this?  I'm not sure.  I jsut want to use chef for it's config management but maybe even in time i will convert to consul templates.  At least the attributes storage piece is now moved to hashicorp ecosystem in consul.